# VIM server support of non-latin characters

Tags: vim

I'm unable to send remotely command to vim with some non-ASCII characters like polish "ę", "ł" etc. It basically makes "ą" to become "a":[image: zażółć gęślą jaźń -> zazólc gesla jazn]

Problem occurs on windows with vim and gvim, for now i'm not able to check that on any linux machine. Can i force vim to use utf-8 in servermode too? Everything else is working properly after reading http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode problem occurs only on --remote-* commands

Comment: FYI It works as expected on Mac OS X. What is the value of `:set encoding?` with the question mark?

Comment: @romainl utf-8, here is my vimrc: http://bin.kadet.net/59ec832dd3a850.43220458 also i asked friend of mine and it also works on his machine, which is also windows so it's little bit strange

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it seems that it has nothing to do with vim or commandline encoding.

The problem was that I had set my fallback locale to "English (United States)" as I prefer english in my workflow rather than my native language, and windows (or more likely vim using windows APIs) seems to convert non-latin characters into closest from selected fallback.

[image: Set fallback locale to polish in region settings]